# How Disable a Dropdown Item When Some Selection Checkboxes Are Not Present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll try my best to explain this. So I have several HTML pages with a dropdown menu, which selects checkboxes when pressed on each item.

HTML Page 1 has checkboxes for female names:

```
Arina
Diana
Jane
....
```

HTML Page 2 has checkboxes for male names:

```
Jake
Andrew
William
....
```

HTML Page 3 has checkboxes for pet names:

```
Milo
Ollie
Teddy
...
```

Now I'm using a dropdown menu on these 3 HTML pages I've mentioned to select these checkboxes.

You can see the live working example for the Girls page from the following code snippet.

But the Javascript/jQuery code I use on these 3 HTML pages (Girls,Boys,Pets) are the same. So here is my Girls HTML page. I'm just attaching the Girls page here, there are two other pages with other data. (Boys, Pets)

```js
$("button.select-girls").on("click", selectGirls);

function selectGirls() {
  $('[data-group="girls"]').prop('checked', !0);

}

$("button.select-boys").on("click", selectBoys);

function selectBoys() {
  $('[data-group="boys"]').prop('checked', !0);

}

$("button.select-pets").on("click", selectPets);

function selectPets() {
  $('[data-group="pets"]').prop('checked', !0);

}


$("button.unselect-all").on("click", unselectAll);

function unselectAll() {
  $('[data-group="girls"], [data-group="boys"], [data-group="pets"]').prop('checked', !1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid py-4">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
      <div class="btn-groups">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 unselect-all">Unselect All</button>

        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Filter</button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
          <button class="dropdown-item select-girls" type="button">Girls</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item select-boys" type="button">Boys</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item select-pets" type="button">Pets</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container col-8 offset-2">
  <div class="table-responsive  shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-light rounded">
    <table id="grid" class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th data-type="string">?</th>
          <th data-type="string">Name</th>
          <th data-type="string">Age</th>
          <th data-type="string">University</th>
          <th class="wfixed" data-type="string">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input checked data-group="girls" type="checkbox" checked />
            <label for="check_us-east"></label>
          </td>
          <td>Arina</td>
          <td class="age"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="uni"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input checked data-group="girls" type="checkbox" checked />
          </td>
          <td>Diana</td>
          <td class="age"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="uni"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input checked data-group="girls" type="checkbox" checked />
          </td>
          <td>Jane</td>
          <td class="age"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="uni"></td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="imageCell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is

1. Disable the dropdown option `Boys, Pets` when in **Girls** page.
2. Disable the dropdown option `Girls, Pets` when in **Boys** page.
3. Disable the dropdown option `Girls, Boys` when in **Pets** page.

Please tell me how to do this. I want to use just a single Javascript file for this because actually there are many HTML pages like this with different combinations (teachers, singers, guitarist like that), I just provided an example for the ease of understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the dropdown? It doesn't appear to do anything...

Comment: Hi, I just provided the example because the actual page is very long.

Comment: OK, but what does it do on the real page?

Comment: For an example, there are several pages like this, Pets, Girls, Boys, Teachers, Singers, Guitarists, like this with a lot of mixed options. I'm trying to use the same Javascript file but disable the unwanted options.

Comment: Simplest way is to do something like `$(".dropdown-menu .select-girls").hide();`

Comment: Something like this -> if input checked data-group="girls" is not found on the page, then disable the Girls dropdown option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So , you have to keep identification of page on each one of the pages for e.g on `Girl` page you have to put something like

`<input type="hidden" value="select-girls" id="identification">`
And then you have to derive which one to be `enable` or `disable` for e.g

```
 var identification=$("#identification").val();
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
      <button class="dropdown-item select-girls"  type="button">Girls</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item select-boys" type="button">Boys</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item select-pets" type="button">Pets</button>
  </div>
 $(".dropdown-item").attr("disabled",true);
 $("."+identification).removeAttr('disabled');
```

So the approach is to `disabled` all the button at first time . And enable only one according to the identification value. Put identification value as same as your one of the class name for e.g `select-girls` on `Girls` page .Now `select-girls` is your `Class Name` use this to remove `disabled` atribute and hence make it only desired button as enabled.Similarly for boys and pets page. for those identification value would be `select-boys` and `select-pets` respectively.

Or

```
   $('.dropdown-item:not(.'+identification+')').attr("disabled",true);
```

`:not()` is faster, presumably because jQuery's selector engine Sizzle can optimise it into a native `.querySelectorAll()` call.

Comment: Thank you. :) Just a quick question, does this method works for mix combinations? Like if we have different combinations.

Comment: It depends upon the condition . It will be better if you show some  other variation too. But i hope you will have pretty clear idea about what to do .

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this answer. I just tried it with a little twist and it worked. :D

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you're getting your type (girls, boys, pets, etc) may with their number-indexes from Back-end. So you can just add some data-type attribute in each button like this:

```
 <button ... data-type="girls" ... >
 <button ... data-type="boys" ... >
 <button ... data-type="pets" ... >
 <button ... data-type="peoplesWhoAnsweringLater" ... >
```

And if you want to have only Girls button enabled, then you can add just this:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').each(function(index, value){
   $(this).prop('disabled', $(this).data('type') != 'girls'); // here you can inject any type of you want from back-end
 });
```

This script will work for different pages and will not thrown an error about other types, if there's not exists them

Comment: @manikant gautam's answer is good, but it just doing N+1 operation instead of N..

disabling all (N) and enabling one (1)